# Apply file structure diff/patch on remote system?

Tags: filesystems, diff

Is there a tool that creates a diff of a file structure, perhaps based on an MD5 manifest. My goal is to send a package across the wire that contains new/updated files and a list of files to remove.  It needs to copy over new/updated files and remove files that have been deleted on the source file structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vfilby I'm the process of implementing something similar.

I've been using rsync for a while, but it gets funky when deploying to remote server with permission changes that are out of my control. With rsync you can choose to not include permissions, but they still endup being considered for some reason.

I'm now using git diff. This works very well for text files. Diff generates patches, rather then a MANIFEST that you have to include with your files. The nice thing about patches is that there is already an established framework for using and testing these patches before they're applied.

For example, with patch utility that comes standard on any *unix box, you can run the patch in  dry-run mode. This will tell you if the patch that you're going to apply is actually going to apply before you run it. This helps you to make sure that the files that you're updating have not changed while you were preparing the patch.

If this is similar to what you're looking for, I can elaborate on my process.

Answer (score 3):

You might try rsync. Depending on your needs, the command might be as simple as this:

```
rsync -az --del /path/to/master dup-site:/path/to/duplicate
```

Quoting from [rsync's web site](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/):

> rsync is an open source utility that
>   provides fast incremental file
>   transfer. rsync is freely available
>   under the GNU General Public License
>   and is currently being maintained by
>   Wayne Davison.

Or, if you prefer [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync):

> rsync is a software application for
>   Unix systems which synchronizes files
>   and directories from one location to
>   another while minimizing data transfer
>   using delta encoding when appropriate.
>   An important feature of rsync not
>   found in most similar
>   programs/protocols is that the
>   mirroring takes place with only one
>   transmission in each direction. rsync
>   can copy or display directory contents
>   and copy files, optionally using
>   compression and recursion.

Comment: I was hoping for something offline at this point.  I am working my way towards online diffs.